# Class member function definition error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I did compilation in VisualStudio2013 for the following code.
I have a class in a layer_factory.hpp like

```
namespace caffe {

    template <typename Dtype>
    class Layer;

    template <typename Dtype>
    class LayerRegistry {
     public:
         typedef shared_ptr<Layer<Dtype> >(*Creator) (const LayerParameter&);
         typedef std::map<string, Creator> CreatorRegistry;

         static CreatorRegistry& Registry();

    }

}
```

I define `Registry()` in `layer_factory.cpp` as

```
namespace caffe {
    template <typename Dtype>
    static LayerRegistry<Dtype>::CreatorRegistry& LayerRegistry<Dtype>::Registry()
    {
        static CreatorRegistry* g_registry_ = new CreatorRegistry();
        return *g_registry_;
    }
}
```

When I compile, I got errors as

```
Error   23  error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation C:\SOFTWARES\Visual_Studio_Workspace\caffe\src\caffe\layer_factory.cpp  23  1   caffe
Error   20  error C2065: 'Dtype' : undeclared identifier    C:\SOFTWARES\Visual_Studio_Workspace\caffe\src\caffe\layer_factory.cpp  19  1   caffe
Error   19  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'  C:\SOFTWARES\Visual_Studio_Workspace\caffe\src\caffe\layer_factory.cpp  19  1   caffe
Error   22  error C2509: 'Registry' : member function not declared in 'caffe::LayerRegistry'    C:\SOFTWARES\Visual_Studio_Workspace\caffe\src\caffe\layer_factory.cpp  23  1   caffe
Error   21  error C2923: 'caffe::LayerRegistry' : 'Dtype' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Dtype'   C:\SOFTWARES\Visual_Studio_Workspace\caffe\src\caffe\layer_factory.cpp  19  1   caffe
```

What could be wrong with this code?
Thanks

Comment: Templates have to pretty much completely live in a header file. You can't define the body in a source file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Thanks now I understand.

Comment: You may miss a `;`  after your class (and should keep errors sorted)